# Dwarfing a tree

Tags: trees, fruits

I wanna know whether if I can use any rootstock to dwarf a tree, or I need to use a specific rootstock and if so what types give what sizes and where to get them. And how do I dwarf a tree in general. (for example, what are M18 rootstocks and from what plant do they come from?)

Comment: Dwarfing rootstocks are most commonly used with apples.  What kind of tree are you interested in?  We need to have more details or this question is too broad

Comment: citrus plants that are not too small and not too big.